# linked list has cycle function review

Tags: c, linked-list

I wrote a code for checking if a linked list input has a cycle but my approach is a bit different than the ones on the internet, does it work?

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */
bool hasCycle(struct ListNode *head) {
    struct ListNode *p1,*p2;
    p1 = head;
    if(p1 == NULL) return 0;
    for(p1 = head;p1->next != NULL;p1 = p1->next){
        for(p2 = p1->next;p2 != NULL;p2=p2->next){
            if(p2 == p1) return 1;
            if (p2 == NULL) return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning too early:

```
    for(p2 = p1->next;p2 != NULL;p2=p2->next){
        if(p2 == p1) return 1;
        if (p2 == NULL) return 0;
    }
```

When `p2` becomes NULL, it just means there's no cycle *involving `p1`*, not there's no cycle at all.  By returning 0 here, you only check the head node for a cycle.

Get rid of the extra return, so you only return 0 when you've searched everything.

```
for(p1 = head;p1->next != NULL;p1 = p1->next){
    for(p2 = p1->next;p2 != NULL;p2=p2->next){
        if(p2 == p1) return 1;
    }
}
return 0;
```

EDIT:

This still won't work as it will go into an infinite loop if the cycle doesn't involve the first node.  The proper way to handle this is to check each node against all prior nodes found.  This can be done by putting nodes in a list as they are visited.  If a node already exists in the list before you add it, you found a cycle.

Alternately, you can put a "visited" flag in each node initialized to 0.  Then traverse the list setting the flag as you go.  If the flag is already set, you have a cycle.

Comment: Could you give an example of a list where OP code fails? Such as _there is no cycle involving `p1`_, but _there is a cycle somewhere else_. Unless I am missing something obvious, it is not possible. It is a linked list after all, not a general DG. PS: AFAICT both OP and your code are bound to an infinite loop in case of a cycle, but it is a different problem.

Comment: Exactly what I mean - `NULL` is never hit. Infinite loop, isn't it?

Comment: @user58697 You are correct, if we're only checking the first node that would be a problem.  To do this correctly would require checking the current node against all before it.  I'll make a change.